# Silverlight redirect when logged in

Tags: silverlight, redirect, authentication

I have a larger silverlight application. If you go straight to the site you will be asked to login.

But the function that I'm looking for is that I now would like to enable users to go straight to a url in my application, and if they're not logged in they will be redirected to the loginpage, and when they have logged in, redirected back.

How would I be able to implement this in a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

David Poll, the navigation guru for Silverlight presents a nice solution in the following blogg post: http://www.davidpoll.com/2010/04/25/a-refreshing-authenticationauthorization-experience-with-silverlight-4/